# How to get specific information from a complex JSON format file C#

Tags: c#, json, object, model

I am trying to attain a List of all "methodname"  "fullname" and property[] values from a complex JSON file, I have tried to implement a basic model to read the top layer but everything returns as null;

```
public class TestRun
{
    public string @id { get; set; }
    public string @name { get; set; }
    public string @fullname { get; set; }
    public string testcasecount { get; set; }
    public TestSuite[] TestSuite { get; set; }
}

public class TestSuite
{

}

public class ScriptModel
{
    public TestRun[] TestRun { get; set; }

}
```

JSON looks like so; From the root level there are a large amount of nested "test-suites" and "test-fixtures"

```
            "test-suite": {
                "@type": "TestSuite",
                "@id": "0-1030",
                "@name": "Example__Exampledll",
                "@fullname": "Example",
                "@runstate": "Runnable",
                "@testcasecount": "24",
                "test-suite": {
                    "@type": "TestSuite",
                    "@id": "0-1031",
                    "@name": "Features",
                    "@fullname": "Payments_Regression.Features",
                    "@runstate": "Runnable",
                    "@testcasecount": "24",
                    "test-suite": [
                        {
                            "@type": "TestSuite",
                            "@id": "0-1033",
                            "@name": "PRE",
                            "@fullname": "Payments_Regression.Features",
                            "@runstate": "Runnable",
                            "@testcasecount": "16",
                            "test-suite": [
                                {
                                    "@type": "TestFixture",
                                    "@id": "0-1015",
                                    "@name": "Outwards",
                                    "@fullname": "Example_Outwards",
                                    "@classname": "Example_Dll_Example_Outwards",
                                    "@runstate": "Runnable",
                                    "@testcasecount": "8",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "property": [
                                            {
                                                "@name": "Description",
                                                "@value": "Smoke"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "@name": "Category",
                                                "@value": "PREPRODUCTION"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "@name": "Category",
                                                "@value": "Payment"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "test-case": [
                                        {
                                            "@id": "0-1017",
                                            "@name": "TestCaseNameIWantToCapture",
                                            "@fullname": "fullnameexample",
                                            "@methodname": "MethodNameToCapture",
                                            "@classname": "ClassNametoCapture",
                                            "@runstate": "Runnable",
                                            "@seed": "1767458888",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "property": {
                                                    "@name": "Description",
                                                    "@value": "PropertyValueiWouldLikeToCapture."
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
```

Comment: Copy your JSON to the clipboard, then in Visual Studio, choose Paste/Special/Paste JSON as classes.   This will write correct classes for your json.

Comment: Seems your `Json` isn't in correct format. Post the valid `Json`

Comment: Use JsontoCsharp site to check your class from here - http://json2csharp.com/ I tried to parse your JSON string bit it seems to something missing in the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You use special symbol `@` it don't change name of variable, this symbol sometimes use for use keywords like variable names `var @object = "sample"`

You need to use `JsonProperty` attribute

```
public class TestRun
{
    [JsonProperty("@id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@fullname")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@testcasecount")]
    public string TestCaseCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("test-suite")]
    public TestSuite[] TestSuite { get; set; }
}
```